# Sampling: If multiple samples produce one output, how many samples do I actually have to work with?

Tags: sampling, sample-size

Explaining, imagine that I compute  a single test statistic from $n$ successive real world samples. And imagine that I obtain a total of $m \gg n$ real world samples during my experiment.

Do I have $m$ or $m \over n$ samples to work with for hypothesis testing?

---

An example whereby I test for a uniform distribution as part of randomness testing:  Assume a total sample size of random 5120 bytes. My test statistic is the peak value of a fast Fourier transformation with an processing window of 512 bytes. So 512 bytes are crunched to produce one floating point number.  I guess that means I only have 10 trials for a KS uniformity test...

For context, I'm thinking about the following statement, taken from [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3693611/#A3505R7):-

> An absolute value of the score greater than 1.96 or lesser than -1.96
> is significant at P < 0.05, while greater than 2.58 or lesser than
> -2.58 is significant at P < 0.01, and greater than 3.29 or lesser than -3.29 is significant at P < 0.001. In small samples, values greater or lesser than 1.96 are sufficient to establish normality of the data.
> However, in large samples (200 or more) with small standard errors,
> this criterion should be changed to ± 2.58...

I believe that this is related to [Sampling: If one sample produces multiple outputs, how many samples do I actually have to work with?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299235/74762) yet is its exact opposite.

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Can you give an actual real-life example of the situation you describe in your first paragraph?

Comment: Are you using the word *sample* to mean observation? See opening parafraphs definition of same in statistics here: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sample_(statistics)&oldid=1056164269 where here we're  looking at an old page because the merger with Sampling lost this definition of sample

Comment: @Glen_b     Yes.......................

Comment: That may cause some confusion.

Comment: @Glen_b Well that was a total waste of time wasn't it?  [Elitism?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitism) Thanks buddy.